# iconv with EBCDIC support on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, iconv, ebcdic

I installed iconv on Cygwin using the setup utility. The version information is as follows:

```
$ iconv --version
iconv (GNU libiconv 1.14)
Copyright (C) .....
Written by Bruno Haible.
```

However `iconv -l` is not showing any EBCDIC related codepages. Is there anything else I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `recode` for my requirement, which had the necessary codepage support available.